# Filter records on a Web2py smartgrid linked table

Tags: web2py

I found web2py Smartgrid forms really powerful, but I don't find how to filter rows on a linked table, based, for instance in a query or similar.

This is the function which returns rows to be displayed (paks):

```
def opened_paks():
    opened = (db.pak.id==db.mov_pak.pak) & (db.mov_pak.event=='Open')
    records = SQLTABLE(db(opened).select(db.pak.ALL))
    return dict(records=records)
```

I require to limit on the grid for the linked table (item_order), once it is selected, **ADD** only rows from opened_paks() set, smartgrid definition:

```
def manage_orders():
    #here is where is needed to define a constraint to limit
    #on item_order form to just pak row from opened_paks()
    grid = SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.order,linked_tables=['item_order'],
                         user_signature=False
                         )
    return dict(grid=grid)
```

Of course item_order and the other models are related:

```
db.define_table('order',
    Field('cliente', 'reference cliente'),
    Field('code','integer'),
    Field('fecha','date',label="Fecha",default=request.now,notnull=True),
    migrate='orden.table',
    format=lambda r: '%s->%s' % (r.code, db.cliente[r.cliente].name ) 
)

db.define_table('pak',
    Field('producto','reference producto'),
    Field('qty','double'),
    migrate='pak.table',
    format=lambda r: '%s->%s' % (r.id, db.producto[r.producto].descripcion )
    )

db.define_table('item_orden',
    Field('order', 'reference order'),
    Field('pak', 'reference pak'),
    Field('qty','double',notnull=True),
    Field('precio_unitario','double',label="Precio Unitario",notnull=True),
    migrate='item_order.table',
    format = '%(orden)s %(paquete)s %(id)s'
    )

db.define_table('mov_pak',
    Field('paquete','reference pak'),
    Field('fecha','date',label="Fecha",notnull=True),
    Field('event',label="Evento",requires=IS_IN_SET(['I','M','Open', 'C'])),
    migrate='mov_pak.table',
    format = '%(paquete)s %(fecha)s %(evento)s'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

With help from the Web2py spanish group, the way to accomplish this is using [common_filters](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/35/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Common-filters), as follows one possible way , they clue anyway is to use common filters:

```
def manage_orders():
    opened = (db.pak.id==db.mov_pak.paquete) & (db.mov_pak.evento=='Open')
    opened_rows = db(opened).select()
    opened_set= set()
    for r in opened_rows:
        opened_set.add(r.pak.id)
    # apply filter, since opened query returns a tuple and filter expects table.id 
    #previous lines were requiered
    db.pak._common_filter = lambda query: db.pak.id.belongs(opened_set)
    grid = SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.orden,linked_tables=['item_order'],
                         user_signature=False, csv=False,
                         )
    return dict(grid=grid)
```